# How to install Redis on window

Tags: command-line-interface

I am trying to install redis on windows.
Download either .msi or .zip file, download latest zip file Redis-x64-3.2.100.zip.
Run redis-server.exe.
Run redis-cli.exe.
when when i run command redis-server.
I shows bash: redis-server: command not found
How to fix it. Please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is going to give you a very old version of Redis (looks like Redis 3.2, Redis 7 is the current version).  To get a newer version of Redis for Windows, use WSL2 and install Redis on Ubuntu.